# While using headerTitle in React native, a long title string makes the whole title disappear

Tags: android, react-native, text, stack

I want to display two lines as part of the screen title.  So I am using the headerTitle option. It works very well for short strings but if the title string is longer than can be accommodated, the whole title becomes blank.
My TitleView component looks like this:

```
const TitleView = ({line1, line2}) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.title}>
          {line1}
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.subTitle}>{line2}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

and the place it is called looks like this:

```
<Stack.Screen
            name="Contents"
            component={ContentsScreen}
            options={({route}) => ({
              headerTitle: (
                <TitleView
                  line1={route.params.title}
                  line2={route.params.lesson}
                />
              ),
            })}
          />
```

I have also tried to add headerContainerStyle and headerTitleStyle as suggested in another post to no avail.

```
<Stack.Screen
            name="Lessons"
            component={LessonsScreen}
            options={({route}) => ({
              headerTitle: (
                <TitleView line1={route.params.title} line2="Lesson Plans" />
              ),
              headerTitleContainerStyle: {flex: 1},
              headerTitleStyle: {flexShrink: 1},
            })}
          />
```

Any help will be appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 0):

Try this might help (Updated)

```
const TitleView = ({line1, line2}) => {
    return (
      <Text style={styles.title}>
          {line1}
         <Text style={styles.subTitle}>{line2}</Text>
      </Text>
    );
};
```

Comment: Not helping.  I got the screenWidth using Dimensions, but that did not make any difference.  The documentation says that the headerTitle gets converted into <text> in one place and in another place it says numberOfLines does not work inside nested <Text> components.  If I put the two together, I believe that the behaviour is as expected.  However, given that my title string is dynamic and using just title (instead of headerTitle) does the truncation correctly, one would expect to see the same behaviour in headerTitle as well.

Comment: You can use text inside another text as I have updated my answer, please check

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani parent text should have flexDirection:'row'. Otherwise child Text elements need new lines.

Comment: You want 2 texts to show vertically? or Horizontally?

Comment: Vertically. One below the other. As title and subtitle.

Comment: I think in that case you should customize your header instead of using it's default